# Is there a way to create a stub app for Windows Phone?

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-store

Let's pretend that a carrier wants to ship my app with their Windows Phone rom. My app is large and they don't want to make their rom download too big.

What I can do on Android is that I can create a blank app that uses the same package name as the real app and is signed with the same signature as the real app. On launch, the stub app opens the Play Store page where the user can install the current version of the app. Once installed, because the package name and signatures match, the app overrides the stub.

I'm not as versed in Windows Phone development as I am in Android Development. Is there a way to do the above on Windows Phone?